# swift save file after download Alamofire

Tags: swift, alamofire

download and save file

```
let destination: DownloadRequest.DownloadFileDestination = { _, _ in
   // var fileURL = self.createFolder(folderName: downloadFolderName)
    var fileURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]

    let fileName = URL(string : currentFile.link )
    fileURL = fileURL.appendingPathComponent((fileName?.lastPathComponent)!)
    return (fileURL, [.removePreviousFile, .createIntermediateDirectories])
}
Alamofire.download(currentDownloadedFile.link , to: destination).response(completionHandler: { (DefaultDownloadResponse) in
    print("res ",DefaultDownloadResponse.destinationURL!);
    completion(true)
})
```

but when i wont to check file in this dirrectory i get nil

```
let filemanager:FileManager = FileManager()
let fileURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
let files = filemanager.enumerator(atPath: fileURL.absoluteString) // = nil
while let file = files?.nextObject() {
    print(file)
}
```

if i save local path to file and after reload app wont to share it -> "share" app cant send file (mb cant found it)

can u pls help me. how it works ? why when i print all files he didnt find it?  how to save file who after reboot app it will be saved in same link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong API

For file system URLs use always `path`, `absoluteString` returns the full string including the scheme (e. g. `file://` or `http://`)

```
let files = filemanager.enumerator(atPath: fileURL.path)
```